# Receber os dados de um utilizador e mostrar esses dados no fim

Tags: c, scanf

Pretendo receber inserir os dados de um utilizador e no fim quando corro o programa pretendo mostrá-los, mas penso que a variável morada não é assim, pois o programa salta do nome para a idade directamente, e primeiro devia deixar inserir a morada e não deixa, o que pretendo é criar um programa em C de modo a guardar os contactos de utilizadores o código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char nome[50], morada[100];
int idade;
int montdep;
long int numconta;

printf("Introduza o seu nome:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",nome);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Introduza a sua morada:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",morada);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Introduza a sua idade:\n");
scanf("%d",&idade);

    if(idade<=-1)
    {
        printf("Não se aceita valores negativos\nReinicie programa");
    }  
    else
    {
        printf("Introduza o valor a depositar:\n");
        scanf("%d",&montdep);
        printf("Introduza o numero de conta :\n");
        scanf("%ld",&numconta);  
        printf("%s com morada%s de %d anos, depositou %d€ na conta %ld",nome,morada,idade,montdep,numconta);
    }    
}
```

o resultado é este:

```
Introduza o seu nome:
luis esquinas
Introduza a sua morada:
Introduza a sua idade:
25
```

como se vê ele não deixa introduzir a morada e aí é que tenho o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o Scanf, ele lê a outra linha também, uma forma de você evitar isso é colocando após o Scanf, um getchar(), ficando assim:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char nome[50]; 
  char morada[100];
  int idade;
  int montdep;
  long int numconta;

  printf("Introduza o seu nome:\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",nome);
  getchar();
  printf("Introduza a sua morada:\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",morada);
  getchar();
  printf("Introduza a sua idade:\n");
  scanf("%d",&idade);

if(idade<=-1)
{
    printf("Não se aceita valores negativos\nReinicie programa");
}  
else
{
    printf("Introduza o valor a depositar:\n");
    scanf("%d",&montdep);
    printf("Introduza o numero de conta :\n");
    scanf("%ld",&numconta);  
    printf("%s com morada %s de %d anos, depositou %d€ na conta %ld",nome,morada,idade,montdep,numconta);
}    
}
```

Comment: Valeu, obrigado, funcionou para o que queria

Comment: De nada, qualquer dúvida só falar =).

Comment: como poderei enviar os dados para um ficheiro txt para uma directoria especifica no pc?